# How can I determine the height of my text that will be drawn in a rectangle?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I'm trying to draw some text in a rectangle w/ GDI+ like described in this Microsoft article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baw6k39s(v=vs.110).aspx.

After specfying the width I want, the text automatically wraps to the next line like intended. The issue is, I need to set the height of the rectangle so that the text fits perfectly within the box, none cut off but no extra whitespace. Trial and error testing with values will simply not work in this case because the text will be changing.

I implemented a solution that mimics the breaking of the text that will occur at rendering by adding newline chars to it then measuring the height. But this does not appear to be working and the height of the box often has a tremendous amount of trailing white space (which seems follow a positive linear relationship to the amount of text).

**The problem:**

[image]

**My code is as follows:**

```
public void setBreakLen() { //determines how many chars fit on each line (note: using a FIXED WIDTH FONT) 
  double cwidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("h", font).Width;
  breakLen = (int)((double)box.Width / (double)cwidth);
}



public void updateHeight() { //should tell me what the height of the box should be to fit perfectly
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
  int numAppended = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) {
      if ((i + 1) % breakLen == 0) {
          sb.Insert((i + 1 + numAppended), "\n");
          numAppended += 1;
       }
   }

   Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(sb.ToString(), font);
   height = s.Height;
   box = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
}
```

However, this just seems like overkill, there must be a better way. 
As such, I suppose this is actually a two part question.

1. How can I make my current solution work?
2. Is there a better way
   to do this?

**NOTE:**
Using the debugger, I've determined that the `breaklen` variable is correct. It reads 11 and there are 11 characters on each line.

I've also checked other chars with the fixed width font (Consolas family) , they all produce identical break lengths. Is this is an issue with how StringBuilder handles newline chars? I usually work with Java not C# so I'm not familiar with the streams and such.

**EDIT:**
Drawing code is as follows:

```
g2d.DrawString(m.text, m.font, Brushes.Blue, m.box);
g2d.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, Rectangle.Round(m.box));
```

**EDIT 2:**
I've tried implemnting this secondary solution with the overload `Size` parameter of `MeasureText` function. This just returns 19 every time despite the length of the string, it seems to be returning the correct height for a SINGLE line.

```
    Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, font, new Size(width, 0));//i also tried MaxInt
    height = s.Height;
    Console.WriteLine(height);
    box = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
```

Comment: Down/close voter please explain? How is this off topic????? The code you see is a MCVE, and this is completely on topic

Comment: Is what you want to do is to specify a limiting width and some how compute the need height to display the text?  If so, use the [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sy6awsb(v=vs.110).aspx) method that takes a proposed size.  For this proposed size, set the height to zero and the returned size will have the required height.

Comment: You need to show some more code related to drawing of rectangle and text.

Comment: Use the overload of MeasureText that takes a `Size`, and pass in a value with a `Height` of `Int32.MaxValue`.  The `Height` of the returned `Size` will then be set to the minimal height needed to render the text.

Comment: @MukulVarshney edited in.

Comment: @BradleyUffner ande TnTinMn ok thanks will try this

Comment: @TnTinMn this doesn't appear to be working, I'll edit in what I did. Now it just returns 19 every time despite the length of the string (how many lines it spans)

Comment: You need to use the overload I provided a link to that also takes a TextFormatFlags argument.  Use `TextFormatFlags fmt = TextFormatFlags.Default | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;`

Comment: @TnTinMn Okay thank you, I apreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code. I just clubbed the code in one function to get it run. You can see the change. You have to use `MeasureString` rather than `MeasureText`. See the output i got 
[image]

```
Font font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12.0F, FontStyle.Bold);

int x = 10, y = 10, width = 120, height = 30, breakLen = 0;
Rectangle box;
string text = "THIS BOX IS TOO TALL!!!";

private void DrawRectangle()
{
    box = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

    using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
    {
        double cwidth = g.MeasureString("h", SystemFonts.DefaultFont).Width;
        breakLen = (int)((double)box.Width / (double)cwidth);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
        int numAppended = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((i + 1) % breakLen == 0)
            {
                sb.Insert((i + 1 + numAppended), "\n");
                numAppended += 1;
            }
        }

        Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(sb.ToString(), font);
        height = s.Height;
        box = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        g.DrawString(sb.ToString(), font, Brushes.Blue, box);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, box);
        pen.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realize GDI+ had a different text measurement method.  Thank you for pointing this out, I'd like to accept. However, I'm still a little bit confused on a couple aspects here. For starters, you use g.MeasureString but you don't feed it the actual font I'm going to use, you use the DefaultFont. Additionaly, you still use MeasureText later.

Comment: Ah, JK, it does work. But, I still don't understand why you use `SystemFonts.DefaultFont` instead of the Font instance I specified. How does that work?

Comment: I played around and it just worked. Why this trick worked, I have no answer.

Comment: The only point in your code that is correct is the use of `MeasureString` instead of `MeasureText`. Everything else is just...rubbish! So in order to get the box you do:`SizeF s = g.MeasureString(text, font, width); box = new Rectangle(x, y, (int)s.width, (int)s.height);`